# Push Notifications Issue app Transfer

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

i transferred my iOS app from my account to another account a month ago  using the new app transfer introduced by apple,  everything was ok ,and push notification was ok . but recently 2 days ago the push notification has stopped, and i didn't figure out why , do i have  to regenerate new certificates?

Comment: is your app on iStore?

Comment: shittt!you don't have anything in hand...try contacting to Apple team!

Comment: i have access to the other account ,but i don't know what to do.

Comment: is your certificates expired? anyway you should try re-generating the certificates in the new developer account.

Comment: no ,my certificates are not expired

Comment: Could you updated what happened with your issue? Would be great for me because I have to transfer a app to another account and my app is using purchases and notifications and need to keep these features working. I have some doubts about this process. Thanks in advance

Comment: well, it turned out that there is nothing wrong with the certificates , the problem was in my server @JuanPedroMartinez

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue on transfer (in beta/TestFlight).

App is on Parse (yeah I know they are shutting down). When I created the new Dev account, push stopped working - everything in xcode, apple developer (profile,  signatures etc.) was valid - but it did not work!

The only thing I could think of was to reissue push certificates (both Dev and Prod) against each account and upload the .p12 files to Parse. Once done, everything started to work again.

Also, make sure you do not have the same bundle ID across the two accounts. In theory, that's the first thing xcode will/should complain about (mine did). Apple support guy highlighted that to me too.

I hope this helps.